# Maintain db connection inside Camel Route

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, apache-camel, datasource

**Requirement**: We create a database connection inside a java application. We need to run all the statements through the same connection on the entire Java application.
**Problem**: Once passing the the created datasource in the Camel route, it apparently creates a new connections.

I am using a DataSource Object that creates a connection to an Oracle database. On this connection i run several statements.

```
Connection myConn = myDBDatasource.getConnection()
```

As a second part, i use the created datasource for my Camel route

```
SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry();
reg.put("myDBDatasource", myDBDatasource);
```

Inside my route, i use a bean that creates a query which finally ends to my database.

```
from("direct:start").bean(MyClass.class,
"processData").to("jdbc:oracleDataSource?resetAutoCommit=false");
```

So the problem in this case that i create a new connection at the start which i want to use throughout the entire application. Once Camel is doing the routing to the DB, it creates a new one.

**Question 1**: Is there any way to maintain somehow the same Connection (myConn) also inside Camel RouteBuilder ? 
**Question 2**: My datasource is already set to DefaultAutoCommit(**false**) . Could it be that inside the RouteBuilder Camel ignores this and still commits the queries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally created my own Custom datasource class and implemented some part also found in the SingleConnectionDataSource of Spring.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring's SingleConnectionDataSource or make a custome one. If you want to prevent Camel from commits use a Connection proxy and disable commit().

Comment: I am not using Spring. Is there any other possible solution without adding extra libraries in my project?